# How to find an unknown exponent given the area between 2 functions?

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $a > 0$ and consider the functions $f(x)=xe^{ax}$ and $g(x) = x$

a) Determine the value of a, given that the area between these functions for $0≤x≤1$ is equal to $1$ square unit.

My attempt:
I know that for x > 0, f(x) > g(x)

so I am going to take the integral of top function and minus the bottom function at 0 and 1.

$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) - g(x)\ dx$

= $\int_{0}^{1} xe^{ax}  - x dx$

using by parts:

= $ e^a\frac{1}{a}-e^a\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{2} = 1$

But Now how am I suppose to solve for $a$? Do i use logs? Am I on the right track? Is there a shorter way? Thanks..

Comment: Generally you can't exactly solve equations involving both $x$ and $e^x$ unless there is some cancellation or if you are allowed to use the special function Lambert's W.  [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ea%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%7D-e%5Ea%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%5E2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%5E2%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D+%3D+1) gives $x \approx 1.55.$

Comment: @JairTaylor Yeah my answer book give a = 1.55, so I must use technology to solve it?

Comment: If it only gives the decimal approximation $a = 1.55$ that's an indication that the authors also did not find an exact-form solution.

Comment: @JairTaylor I see. Thanks.

Comment: @JairTaylor.I am not sure that there is a solution in terms of Lambert function. If you have one, I am very interested (this is not a joke). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, I don't have a solution.  I was just speaking generally.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hey, were you talking to me? I don't see any mistakes? Thanks.

Comment: In the first line, you wrote $f(x)=x\,\color{red}{a}^{ax}$ and later you use $f(x)=x\,\color{red}{e}^{ax}$

Comment: @JairTaylor. You are correct. There is an explicit solution in terms of the generalized Lambert function (have a look at the bottom of my answer). Nice from a formal point of view but .... of no use ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with what you very correctly did, since it is obvious that $a \neq 0$, we can reduce to common denominator and face the problem of finding the zero('s ?) of function
$$f(a)=2 (a-1) e^a-3 a^2+2$$ This is a transcendental equation (mixing exponential and polynomial terms) and, most of the time, there is no explicit solution except, sometimes, in terms of special function.

The first derivatives are
$$f'(a)=2 a \left(e^a-3\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(a)=2 (a+1) e^a-6$$ The first derivative cancels for $a=0$ and $a=\log(3)$. By the second derivative test $(f''(0)=-4)$ the first point corresponds to a maximum $(f(0)=0)$ and the second one $(f''(\log(3))=6 \log (3))$ to a minimum $(f(\log(3))=-4-3 \log ^2(3)+6 \log (3)<0)$. So, the root we look for is greater than $\log(3)$.

Taking all this information into account, we can now generate an *estimate* of the solution developing $f(a)$ as Taylor series around $a=\log(3)$. This gives
$$f(a)=-\left(4+3 \log ^2(3)-6 \log (3)\right)+3 \log (3) (a-\log (3))^2+O\left((a-\log
   (3))^3\right)$$ which gives
$$a_0=\log (3)+\sqrt{\frac{4+3 \log ^2(3)-6 \log (3)}{3 \log (3)}}\approx 1.657$$ which is not to bad since, up to now, almost no calculus was used.

Now, we need to polish the root and Newton method will be simple. Starting with $a_0$ as defined above, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n      \\
 0 & 1.657419 \\
 1 & 1.569271 \\
 2 & 1.555003 \\
 3 & 1.554653
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit** *just for your curiosity*

In fact, the equation to be solved could rewrite
$$e^{-a}=\frac 23 \frac{(a-1)}{\left(a-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right) \left(a+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right)}$$ which has a formal solution in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

This is nice from a formal point of view but not practical at all.

Comment: Incredible stuff! Thanks!

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk. This is not incredible at all. It is even quite basic and I am sure that you will do even better ... later. Do not forget that I learnt all that stuff 62+ years ago ! Cheers :-)